Selecting SDK in Android Studio Koala
Hopefully someone can answer this. I've just downloaded Android Studio Koala via Flatpak on Linux Mint and I'm confused by the SDK manager.
It has installed Android API 35 but nothing else. I'm a complete novice to this, as when I last downloaded Studio on another machine over four years ago, it was a case of importing an existing app source and you didn't need to worry about anything else.
My app targets SDKs from 26 to 34, and I'm doing my testing on an Android 12 phone (API 31). My JDK compile version is Java 11 and I have downloaded openjdk-11 .
My question is; do I need to download any other SDKs via the manager to allow testing and eventual deployment? As I say, this is the first time I've encountered this and I'm scratching my head.

it would be best if you had SDK on which you will compile your App
suppose you have compiled SDK is 34 then you need to install 34 SDK via manager and accordingly build tools and emulator.
it would be better if you installed SDK 26 and its build tool + its emulator
addition to make sure your JDK is updated accordingly to the Gradle version

Thanks, I'm still a bit bewildered though. I've just looked at my old laptop with the previous version of studio (I can't use this machine for a number of reasons, mainly technical). The $HOME/Android/Sdk mentions android-30, android-31, android-32 so they're obviously I used for development previously. Should I ensure that the directory structure, files etc, are the same on my new laptop?
In the past, I'd just build, plug the phone in, install the new software and then test it. I'd then build a release version without changing anything, upload it and bingo.
